# Get all data between months in a span of years

Tags: mysql, date

Sorry so this is something I've been trying to figure out for a while now and can't seem to get.

I have a database with a column, Month, and I want to get all of the months between November and May of the next year between 1990 and 2010. This is something where I'm just at a complete loss of where to go and I've tried using:

```
DATE_ADD(Month, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND YEAR(Month) BETWEEN 1990 AND 2010
```

With no luck.

The examples I've been seeing are people who want to use `CURDATE` which isn't the case here.

Comment: Anything you've tried so far? Post your table along with the query you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
WHERE (MONTH(date) >= 11 AND YEAR(date) BETWEEN 1990 AND 2009) OR
      (MONTH(date) <= 5  AND YEAR(date) BETWEEN 1991 AND 2010)
```

This assumes that you have a column called `date` which is one of MySQL's date types.  The first condition in the `WHERE` clause matches November and December of 1990 (but not the spring of that year), as well as November/December of all years up until 2009.  The second condition matches January-May of 1991 up to and including 2010.

Comment: Ah thank you! I had a feeling it was just me phasing out on some basic logic for the date...